# Simple cipher stops working in loop

Tags: c++, encryption

For the first run around, the cipher will encrypt the string.  But if I want to loop through again, I can't get the cipher to encrypt a second string.

Is there was a way to make this possible without using pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char checkSum[63] = "QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLPqazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp1234567890"; //checksum
string message; //original message
string messageEncrypted; //replaces pointer
char YorN;
//int multiplier; //part of the prototype

int main(int argc, char *argz[])
{


    do
    {
        cout << "enter a message to encrypt: ";
        getline(cin, message);
        messageEncrypted = message; //i could use a pointer for this i think but I keep running into problems

        for (unsigned count = 0; count <= messageEncrypted.length(); count++) //cycles through characters in string
        {

            //multiplier = messageEncrypted.length() + (int)messageEncrypted[count]; //declaring prototype
            //messageEncrypted[count] = (int)messageEncrypted[count] * multiplier; //prototyped idea that doesn't work

            while ((int)messageEncrypted[count] > 62) //checks to make sure it is withen the value range of checkSum
            {
                messageEncrypted[count] -= ('A' - 3); //puts it into that range
            }

            messageEncrypted[count] = checkSum[(int)messageEncrypted[count]]; //redeclares character

        }

        cout << "Encrypted message is: \n" << messageEncrypted << endl; //prints out encrypted message
        cout << "\nRun again [y/n] ";
        cin >> YorN;

    } while (YorN == 'y'||YorN=='Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I want to loop through again, I can't get the cipher to encrypt a second string.

The problem is that after you've read the response from the user using:

```
cin >> YorN;
```

The newline character is still left on input stream. The next call to `getline()` just reads the newline. Add a line to ignore the rest of the line:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

immediately after

```
cin >> YorN;
```